# Changing columns in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

So I made a seperate migration file to change  the  name of a column in my database table. The problem is when I try to go the page with the table I get an undefined method error on the column name I tried to change.

My professor told me I have to change the View/controller before The columns will work but I can not find  out what I have to do.. any help/suggestions?

The way I'm changing the columns is like this:

```
class FixColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
rename_column :suppliers, :sName, :"first_name"
add_column :suppliers, :"last_name"
remove_column :suppliers, :Snum
remove_column :parts, :Ptnum
end
end
```

[image: error message in browser]

Comment: Please post your error message.

Comment: yes, I migrate and then get the error.

Comment: I posted the message i get in the browser

Comment: `:"first_name"` and `:first_name` are equivalent FYI. There is no reason to use `:"first_name"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've chaned the name of the database column, then you'll also need to change the name of the associated Model's attribute in your application code.

That is, if you previously had `@supplier.sName` (or similar), you'll now need `@supplier.first_name` (or something similar - using the new column names).

Comment: I'm quite new to rails. When you say associated Model's attribute, where exactly are you directing me? Under the models directory?

Answer (score 1):

sNum not longer exist.

remove

```
<%= @supplier.sNumb %>
```

you will change

```
<%= @supplier.sName %>
```

to

```
<%= @supplier.first_name %>
```

you will also want to add

```
<%= @supplier.last_name %>
```

Comment: when I delete @supplier.sNum
It then gives me the error undefined method sName.

Comment: because you changed the sName to first_name  change like above